# Youmail visual voicemail in a foreign country?

Tags: geolocation, voicemail

[Youmail](http://www.youmail.com/home/index) is one of my favorite apps to get voicemail to download onto my phone. However, I am now in Israel for the year, but I would still like to be able to use it.

The way it seems to work right now, is it changes the forwarding number and the number to retrieve voicemails from. This makes it difficult to use in a foreign country because the country codes are required, and they vary based on phone service.

**Is there a way to get youmail to work even in a foreign country?**

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't feasable.

I take it you now have an Israel cell phone now, and you are trying to get Youmail on that. Youmail is a U.S. based service, so even if you got forwarding to work for voicemail, it would eat up into your balance like nothing else. It would be the same as you calling the U.S. based number every time someone left a voicemail; I'm sure Israel to U.S. calls are not free.

However, if your U.S. friends still call your old U.S. cell phone, those will still get directed to youmail (assuming the cell phone account is still active). You would simply check the messages via the internet.

Comment: If that is the case, do you know of any other similar voice mail services that work internationally?